# Can I add my own modules to python in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using VS Code for some time now, and I can't figure out how to add my own modules. I've been wanting to use Pygame, but it's not in the marketplace.

Comment: You don't add them to VSCode from marketplace, you install them for the interpreter that will be used in VSCode. Note you can have multiple interpreters and change which one to use

Comment: See also [Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python). It's all about setting up your python toolchain correctly. There is also a [Install and use packages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-and-use-packages) section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue: I'm using a my school laptop and the firewall won't let me access the command prompt. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned, pygame is a python module, not a vscode extension. To install it, go to your vscode command prompt and type,

```
pip install (module name)
```

In your case, you would want:
`pip install pygame`

Comment: I typed it in and got this:

Comment: pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install pygame
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException